# I am opening a browser and logging in into a webpage. Now i want to open a new tab and work with another link in the newly opened tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

String baseUrl = "https://accounts.zoho.in/signin?servicename=google";

driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login_id\"]"));
email.sendKeys("xxxxxxxx.xmail.com");
WebElement nextbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nextbtn\"]"));
nextbutton.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]"));
password.sendKeys("123456789");
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nextbtn\"]"));
submit.click();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
newTab.remove(oldTab);
driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
}
```

Can someone help me with this code please?  My code is not working (I am a total beginner).  I am able to login as per my requirement, But  i am not able to open a new tab and also need help in going to another link in the newly opened tab.

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at newProject.MyFirstClass.main(MyFirstClass.java:80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript executor

```
    String baseUrl = "https://accounts.zoho.in/signin?servicename=google";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()"); //open window 1
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()"); //open window 2
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()); //number of window WindowHandler array
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); 
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(2)); 
    driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com");
```

Hope it will solved your problem